# How to get real http request in Tomcat behind an Apache?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I'm running a Tomcat webserver on `http` port `8080`. In front I have an Apache that handles `https` `ssl` connections.

How can I know if the client made a request using `http://` or `https://`? Because the following shows `http` always, because the Apache internally sends only `http:8080` requests to the Tomcat of course. So the initial scheme requested is lost here.

```
HttpServletRequest req;
req.getRequestURL().toString(); // always shows http://....
```

Comment: Log the request headers, see if it is something there.

Comment: What do you mean by _handles `https` connections_? you redirect them to `http`?

Comment: Yes, it redirecty to http interally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache should add following request headers as explained in [mod_proxy docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers):

- `X-Forwarded-For` - The IP address of the client.
- `X-Forwarded-Host` - The original host requested by the client in the Host HTTP request header.
- `X-Forwarded-Server` - The hostname of the proxy server.

Additionally `X-Forwaded-Proto` with the original protocol can be added [as explained in this example](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2012/08/08/setting-up-apache-as-a-ssl-front-end-for-play/):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  <strong>RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"</strong>
```

Comment: This is also covered in the `spring-boot` docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server. Important is also to enable `server.use-forward-headers=true` in  `application.properties`